# Remap key to two modifers or use meta shortcuts in terminal (terminator)

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout, xkb, xmodmap

**Background:** *Running Arch Linux on KDE. KDE shortcuts have a problem with being saved past reboot so i'm using xmodmap and xbindkeys.*

So I am using xmodmap. Right now caps lock is mapped to meta (hyper_L) which is assigned to Mod4 (along with Super). I am trying to use the meta shortcut (meta+c) that I've assigned to open chromium. While it works while I'm focused on some applications (like settings), in terminal it simply types c. When i changed the shortcut to <kbd>ctl</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>, it worked.

So:

**How do I use meta shortcuts in terminal (terminator)?**

or

**How can I map caps lock to two modifiers** (either ctl+shift, ctl+super, or ctl+alt) as opposed to just being mapped to one modifier? And do you have a recommendation on what combo would be best for custom shortcuts as not to interfere with most other shortcuts?

**My .xmodmap looks like this:**

```
clear Lock
clear Mod4
add Mod4    = Super_L Super_R Hyper_L
keycode 66 = Hyper_L
```

**and xmodmap yields:**

```
shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock      
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_R (0x6c),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

Comment: You need XKB for that, xmodmap alone can't make a single key apply two modifiers.